# Abelian subcategory which is not a Serre subcategory

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Is there an example of an abelian subcategory $\mathcal{B}$ of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ such that :

- The inclusion functor $\mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{A}$ is exact.
- $\mathcal{B}$ is not closed under extension, i.e. there exists an exact sequence $A'\rightarrowtail A\twoheadrightarrow A''$ in $\mathcal{A}$, such that $A'$ and $A''$ are in $\mathcal{B}$ and $A$ is not isomorphic to any object in $\mathcal{B}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The category of abelian groups of exponent $2$ (i.e., $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces) is an abelian subcategory of the category of abelian groups, but there is an exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to0.$$